# Election system where votes dictate the power of the representative

Tags: election, voting-systems, one-person-one-vote, proportional-representation

Has there ever been a system where the votes received were the measure of power each winning candidate had in the legislature?  I have found this under the name [Direct Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_representation) and [Interactive Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_representation).

This seems like a straight forward solution to the problems which people usually try to solve with Proportional Representation. If your candidate does not win then your vote could be passed to another candidate from their party.

Has anything like this ever been done or only proposed? Are there any issues with doing this as a modification to the Westminster System?

**Please note** this is a different question to [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/why-not-give-representatives-as-many-votes-as-they-received-in-the-election). In that question the weight is determined by the margin and in this system the weight is determined by votes received plus transfers from other constituencies. Furthermore, the question was never answered there. The answers all discussed [Proportional Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_representation) (seat to popular vote ratio for parties) which would remain unchanged. This would get at the underlying issue but by changing the power of the individual representative with no reference to the Proportional Represenation.

Comment: What happens if one candidate gets more than 50% of the vote?  Does anything they want to make law become law?

Comment: This would need to be in a system where there are electoral constituencies. This would mean the max % of the national vote would be the inverse of the number of constituencies.

Comment: "Has anything like this ever been done or only proposed?" is not a duplicate.

Comment: And the answer is "Yes, it has been used": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegative_democracy#Examples

Comment: Some of those are quite clearly a Delegative Democracy not Direct Representation. I was thinking about this as a change to the Westminster System which maintained the SMP but adjusted their power.